# Is there a way to Iterate all Controllers/Actions in an ASP.NET MVC3 Site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to make a dynamic menu function in an ASP.NET MVC 3 website - and I'd like to know if there is a built-in way to get all of the Controllers and Actions at runtime?

I realize that I can use reflection to find all public methods on my controllers, but this doesn't exactly give me the relative URL that I should put in the `<a href="...">` tag.

Also, I'm going to be decorating some of the 'actions' with filter attributes that dictate whether the current user can see/goto those pages. So it would be best if I had access to the filters as well so as to be able to call the `IsAccessGranted()` method.

What are my options? What is the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in mechanism in MVC to enumerate over all of your controllers and actions. You would have to use reflection to inspect all the loaded types and look at their methods and the associated attributes. Of course this is assuming that you are using the default reflection-based action dispatching mechanism. Since MVC's pipeline can be replaced in a number of places its easy to inject a system for invoking action methods that is not based on CLR classes and methods. But if you have complete control over your application than you life is easier.

Answer (score 3):

I actually just did that two weeks ago.

```
var q = from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where type.IsClass && type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.Contains("Controller")
        select type;
        q.ToList().ForEach(type => doWhatYouNeedToDo(type)));
```

if you are using T4MVC, then this script will return double entries. To avoid this, work with

```
&& !type.Name.Contains("T4MVC")
```

In the method doWhatYouNeedToDo() you could transform the Type object into a DTO that suits your needs and add work further with it.

As far as your dynamic menu is concerned, you could use the MvcSiteMapProvider and implement your own dynamic sitemapprovider with it, so you are no longer bound to the static sitemap xml file.

But reflection is quite slow in .NET, so you might want to store representations of your controllers and method in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TVMVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC). You'll still have to use reflection, but the t4 templates will generate a class that's easier to iterate over.